# Access: Using table data in one column as field names in another table

Tags: ms-access

Okay, I have one table that is a list of items.  I want that list of items as field names for another table.  I want to be able to add to the list, easily, which will, in turn, add new field names/columns to this other table.  Example:

Table 1

ID  |  Name

1   |  Bob

2   |  Paul

3   |  John

Table 2

ID  |  Bob  |  Paul  |  John

1   |   y   |   n    |   y

Comment: Hi, can you share any code from your attempts to do this?  You will get better answers if we see your thinking on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store the data like the second table. It isn't normalised and will lead to a whole world of pain further on. You should store that data something like;

> `ID | PersonID | Value
>     1       1      y
>     2       2      n`

This will be easier to query and won't require a re-design when Harry arrives.

You can create a crosstab query to display it like your example.